# Approximate magnetic susceptibility of these liquid propellants?

Tags: physical-chemistry, reference-request, optical-properties, magnetism

This [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14313) asks if the comparatively large paramagnetic susceptibility of liquid oxygen (LOX) is considered when designing rocket tank and engine systems. This [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14313/#comment37525_14326) suggests fuels such as RP-1 (kerosene-like) and liquid hydrogen (often used in [liquid-propellant rockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-propellant_rocket)) do not have a susceptibility as large.

I'd like to find either the approximate or even ballpark values for the magnetic susceptibility of the following four materials, or at least a source where they might be found:

1. liquid oxygen ([LOX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_oxygen))
2. liquid hydrogen ([LH2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_hydrogen))
3. [RP-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RP-1) (rocket fuel), and
4. liquid [methane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methane) ([LNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquefied_natural_gas))

I have tried google searches of various permutations of terms, but so far no luck beyond the one value I was able to cite in that question (LOX susceptibility [here](https://www.pmmh.espci.fr/fr/gouttes/Publications_files/Piroird2013.pdf)).

I'm fairly sure that the susceptibility of the other three are much smaller (100× or more) than that of LOX. For example here is what I can do now:

1. LOX: use the value reported in the link above; 3.5E-03
2. LH2: This [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/41526/16035) links to this [table](http://www.fizika.si/magnetism/MagSusceptibilities.pdf) which lists the susceptibility of liquid hydrogen -5.44E-06 cm³/mol. If I use a density of 0.07 g/cm³ and molar mass of 2.0 g/mol (both from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_hydrogen)) I get approximately -1.9E-07.
3. RP-1: decide that for *paramagnetic and diamagnetic susceptibility*, kerosene and crude oil are very roughly equivalent and use -1E-08 m³/kg from section I of [this](http://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs/32405.pdf) along with a density of order of magnitude 1000 kg/m³ to get a susceptibility of roughly -1E-05
4. LNG: - same argument as RP-1, roughly -1E-05

Comment: Liquid oxygen will be the only paramagnetic substance in this list (it has two unpaired electrons). The others are all diamagnetic. But oxygen is an oxidiser not a full and the others are all fuels. So is the question whether the oxidisers associated with the fuels are paramagnetic?

Comment: @matt_black if you look carefully you'll see I never called oxygen a fuel. I did however call it and all the rest propellants, which is the standard terminology in rocket-speak. There are some great videos in [Is the Paramagnetism of Liquid Oxygen Ever Considered in Engine or Tank Design?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14313/12102) and it's already helpful that you point out that the others propellants are likely to have much weaker responses to magnetic field than LOX, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As it has been pointed out, molecular oxygen is paramagnetic. It is exceptional in that. Usually, you require either a transition metal ion, or a lanthanide ion, or a radical, for a molecule to be paramagnetic.

For most other molecules, including as far as I can tell the fuels you mention, you can safely assume that they are diamagnetic. Paramagnetism is relatively tricky and intense, diamagnetism, at least in its magnitude, is weak and comparatively straightforward to estimate.

If one wants an inexpensive, ballpark estimate of diamagnetism, many people use [Pascal's constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_constants), additive terms considering the involved atoms, with corrections for certain bonds. Rather than Pascal's original work, maybe check out the widely cited Gordon A. Bain  and John F. Berry, [Diamagnetic Corrections and Pascal's Constants](https://doi.org/10.1021/ed085p532), *J. Chem. Educ.* 2008, 85, 4, 532.